# How to programmatically determine the SSL/TLS protocols enabled in Windows server

Tags: c#, ssl, cryptography, wcf-security, tls1.2

Which SSL or TLS protocols a particular Windows server supports, and which of these are enabled, is stored in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
```

Does .NET contain any simple method of enumerating and examining these protocols, so an application running on the server can determine which are enabled?

I know I could query the registry, but there are issues with this:

1. Changes to these registry entries don't take effect until a server reboot - I need to know the currently in-use protocols
2. It is not clear what effect the various values have. There is a DisabledByDefault value and an Enabled value - [most articles](http://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/) say 0 and 1 means a protocol is enabled, but what would 1 and 1 mean? [Some articles](https://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12) confusingly indicate that Enabled should be 0xffffffff not 1.